# How to add a row to a table?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

**What I want to achieve:**
If a child table has a row filled, I want to add a new row.

**What I have tried**
 because I have 10 parent tables underneath each other I cannot use `Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` as it will only count the last parent table.

So I tried doing it with listobjects.

When I try to add a listobject:

```
With Worksheets("Uitwendige scheidingen")
    .ListObject.Add(Range("F" & NextRow + 25)).Name = "tbl_schuindak_orientatie" & Rij
End With
```

(Rij = the parent table)

(NextRow = start position  of the parent table)

I get the error 438

**Note**
I do not have any listobjects added in the sheet before so the parent tables are basicly 'fake' tables and not listobjects.

Comment: You don't set a `ListObject` through it's name property. You first add it, then set it's name.

Comment: You mean it like this? ```.ListObject.Add (Range("F" & NextRow + 25))```
Because that still gives me the same error :/

Comment: I have added a simplified example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you have to `.Add` a `ListObject` to the `ListObjects` collection. Furthermore, you can't set a new `ListObject` through it's `Name` property. You first have to initialize it with a proper source range. Then rename it after. As a simplistic example:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim nxt As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 1 To 10 Step 3
        Set tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Source:=.Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 1, 1)), XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
        tbl.Name = "Table" & x
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Now apply this logic to your situation.

**Note:** See how `xlYes` is applied to tell the `XlListObjectHasHeaders` parameter in this example it needs to take into consideration my source ranges have headers. Set to `xlNo` if yours don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! This will help me a lot!